# My Regex Doesn't Work As I Expected

Tags: java, regex

Heres my regex pattern:

```
[A-Z][a-z]?-?([A-Z][a-z]?)?
```

I want this regex to match the following:

```
A
Ab
Ef-G
Hi-Jk
F-Tk
F-D
```

I'm sending it "M-F" and it matches only on "F", I want it to match the entire string "M-F".

Heres my java code (but hopefully you shouldn't have to read it):

```
// Convert the daycode string into an array of daycodes
ArrayList<String> newDP = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-z]?-?([A-Z][a-z]?)?", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(dayPattern);
while (regexMatcher.find())
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++)
  {
    newDP.add(regexMatcher.group(i));
  }
}
```

Help me? Please and thank you.

**Edit:**
I also need this to scale such that with an input of:

```
MTu-ThFSa
```

Returns an output of:

```
["M", "Tu-Th", "F", "Sa"]
```

Comment: I don't think you mean that you want the regex to match *only* the 5 strings you listed.  I'd recommend changing the wording "I want this regex to match on these, and only these" to be less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only adding groups 1 and upwards:

```
for (int i = 1; ...
```

With a regex match, group 0 is the overall match. Group 1 in your example is just the group in  the second brackets: `([A-Z][a-z]?)?`.

You should just change your loop to access group 0, which will be the whole match:

```
while (regexMatcher.find())
{
    newDP.add(regexMatcher.group(0));
}
```

#### For your edit in the original post:

Here is a fixed regex:

```
[A-Z][a-z]?(-[A-Z][a-z]?)?
```

The hyphen should only be allowed if there is a following letter.

Comment: The actual solution was a combination of your answer as well as Spur's answer. Spur was wrong about the anchors, but he was right to change my Regex to "[A-Z]([a-z](-([A-Z]([a-z])?)?)?)?" Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: Without the anchors it will match any and all strings containing a capital letter, will it not?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I know that with the anchors it matches absolutely nothing.

Comment: WOW, false alarm. It worked on the example I added in my edit, but it doesn't match properly on "M-F". It returns ["M", "F"].

Comment: @Ring: I've updated the answer for your edit in your original post. Regarding your comment: The code I posted here (with your original regex) worked correctly for "M-F". The changed regex you posted broke that...

Comment: Running code - this shows correct output for original question: http://ideone.com/tGOyL The regex you posted as a comment above was not correct. Here's the version for your extended question: http://ideone.com/mF2TC Apologies for the badly-formatted code :)

Comment: You win, you are absolutely correct on all accounts, Supr's regex is wrong. Thank you for all your help! (Man regex is hard sometimes...)

Answer (score 4):

Force it to match the whole string by using [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html): `^[A-Z][a-z]?-?([A-Z][a-z]?)?$`

Though you should probably change the groupings a bit to really only match those. Something like:

```
^[A-Z]  ([a-z]  (-  ([A-Z]  ([a-z])?  )?  )?  )?$
        |-------------------------------------|
                |-------------------------|
                    |-----------------|
                            |-----|
```

Comment: I used this regex string: "^[A-Z]([a-z](-([A-Z]([a-z])?)?)?)?$" (which is exactly what you said to use, just flattened out the spaces) and it didn't match on anything now. Wow, I should have just kept with my for loop and if conditions over the string's characters instead of using regex.... Also, the original regex with ^ and $ at front and beginning still matched only the "F".

Comment: @Ring, try without the spaces

Comment: The original with `^` and `$` only got you the "F" because of what Porges says in his answer.

Comment: Your regex doesn't work for the input use case "M-Th" (with expected output ["M-Th"]).  (Regardless of anchors not working.) The problem with your regex is that it requires a lowercase letter (like "Mo-T") after the first capital letter in order to match on the -Xx.

Comment: That was never specified as a possible input use case. All your examples have a lower case letter before the dash.

Comment: Excellent point, my mistake. I updated the post with all possible inputs to make it crystal clear.